# Bluetooth android python

Tags: bluetooth

Sorry, could you help me with the Bluetooth socket. I am trying to start the server on my smartphone via the built-in socket module, but it gives an error: the socker module has not attributed AF_BLUETOOTH. Could you tell me a simple Bluetooth socket module. And could you please drop the code if possible. Thanks in advance.

I try create app kivy via Bluetooth